# Edited my .htaccess file and now website is downloading, not displaying anymore

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, google-chrome

I made changes to my .htaccess file and now the website is not loading anymore. Instead, it just downloads a file called "download". This happens on Google Chrome, but on Safari the website still gets displayed for some reason.

Here is the htaccess file:

```
text/x-generic .htaccess ( ASCII English text )
AddHandler php-stable .php
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ajax-call$ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ghost-admin/(.*) /wp-admin/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ghost-login$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ghost-login/(.*) /wp-login.php$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?lostpass$ /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?register$ /wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?disconnect$ /wp-login.php?action=logout [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/modules/d0f4711431/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/hide-my-wp/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/modules/7a4b468ee8/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/amp/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/modules/b066722ba6/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/pc-google-analytics/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/modules/f73730c2cd/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/modules/73643f7e3f/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/sumome/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/modules/cec2025f55/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/wp-smushit/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/modules/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/2fe1895cc8/design.css$ /wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/2fe1895cc8/(.*) /wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/bdeaa7676e/design.css$ /wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/style.css [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/bdeaa7676e/(.*) /wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/6ca4266385/design.css$ /wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/style.css [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/6ca4266385/(.*) /wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/fc664c683b/design.css$ /wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/fc664c683b/(.*) /wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/f1dfeb5569/design.css$ /wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/style.css [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/f1dfeb5569/(.*) /wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/96f874eecb/design.css$ /wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/style.css [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/96f874eecb/(.*) /wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/70da61391b/design.css$ /wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/style.css [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/70da61391b/(.*) /wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/views/(.*) /wp-content/themes/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?storage/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?core/(.*) /wp-content/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?lib/(.*) /wp-includes/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?comments/(.*) /wp-comments-post.php$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?writer/(.*) /author/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN (mt) controlled settings
AddHandler php-latest .php
# END (mt) controlled settings
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/404" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php73___lsphp .php
DirectoryIndex index.html INDEX.HTML Index.html index.shtml index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
## BEGIN Compability settings for mt
<IfModule mod_env.c>
  SetEnv DATABASE_SERVER localhost
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=SITE_ROOT:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}]
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=SITE_CGIROOT:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cgi-bin]
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=SITE_HTMLROOT:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}]
</IfModule>
## END Compability settings for mt
```

The file that's get downloaded is just named "download" and contains the following content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: And if you change your .htaccess back to the WordPress default, does it then work?  i.e. are you certain it is something in the .htaccess?

Comment: What did you change? What URL(s) are you requesting? "downloads a file called "download"" - How do you know it's called "download"? Are you _redirected_? What is the domain you are requesting? `example.com`? Or `<something>.example.com`? Or something else?

Comment: I wonder if the issue is with one of the AddHandler blocks.   Does the downloaded file show the website HTML or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Here are few tips to avoid this kind of issue, and to get back to normal:

1. **Regularly backup your ".htaccess" file**, especially before important edits.
2. Before uploading a new ".htaccess" file to your server, **always rename existing one with the last date** and time it was in use ".htaccess_until_2023-04-07_12h30".
3. **If you have an existing backup, use a text file comparison tool**, to highlight the differences between two ".htaccess" files displayed side by side, and find more easily which new edit may have caused the issue. Windows users **can use [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/)** (or similar editor) for this task. In PSPad, open the corrupted ".htaccess" file, right-click the file tab, in the contextual menu, click "Compare with file ...", and lastly pick the last valid backup. As you are likely a Mac user, there is very likely some equivalent for Mac.
4. If you didn't backup your ".htaccess" file, **you could try with the one coming coming from a fresh install** of your CMS. Does this solve your issue? If yes, you could progressively copy the lines of your corrupted ".htaccess" file until finding which line was causing the issue. But don't forget to backup first your existing .htaccess file.
5. Try to see if your web hosting company has some backup of a previously working version of your file.
6. Data recovery approach (more difficult): by **using a file carver** based on file signatures, you can examine your whole hard drive and extract **find past versions of ".htaccess" files**, that are still on your hard drive. This will work only if the disk is unencrypted, and only with Hard Disk Drives (HDD) and not Solid State Drives (SSD), because for the later ones, the TRIM function that is sent by modern operating systems (from the time of Windows 7), will make the SSD auto-clean past data. If you have a recent Mac, forget it. As file carver, **you can for instance use [Scalpel](https://www.kali.org/tools/scalpel)**, which let you specify custom file signatures. You can install is on an existing Linux distro, or find it preinstalled on some live Linux distros, that you can run from an USB stick or CD/DVD. For sure, not the easiest way, but sometimes very useful.
   **Warning**: if you are not familiar enough with Linux, it is important to take time enough to understand what your are doing.

As concerning the differences you observe with Google Chrome and Safari, make sure you **clear your browser history**. I would also recommend clearing the DNS cache if you moved the site from one web hosting to another.

Just a few ideas from someone that is not himself a Wordpress user.

Answer (score 2):

It could be conflict with the PHP version that your server is running.

I suspect this line is causing the problem:
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php73___lsphp .php`
`

Read this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58438365/addtype-in-htaccess-causes-either-download-or-http-error-500